# Block only external access to wp-cron.php on OpenLiteSpeed

Tags: htaccess, wp-cron, xml-rpc

I use OpenLitespeed server with multiple Wordpress installation and want to restrict external access to some files, only allowing server itself to access them (for example to call cron), so:

What I did:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-trackback.php|xmlrpc.php|wp-cron.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Result:

```
    /xmlrpc.php - returns 403 as expected;
    /wp-trackback.php - returns 403 as expected;
    /wp-cron.php - shows white page like it always does without any restrictions...
```

Why so? Any suggestions?

Comment: Where have you placed this code in relation to the other directives in your `.htaccess` file? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? You mention "multiple WP installs"... where is this `.htaccess` located? Do you have other `.htaccess` files olong the filesystem path? And this is for a standard request in the browser over HTTP?

Comment: Why? Without access to these files functionality will break for certain features and plugins, e.g. Jetpack relies on XMLRPC to avoid sites that don't have the REST API yet breaking

Comment: @MrWhite I'm talking about just a single WP installation with a .htaccess in root directory. Nothing special. There are some of the rules made by LScache plugin and standard WP rules there as well. So, exactly this code is placed at the bottom but I also tryied to place it above everything. No changes. It doesn't work for HTTP requests to wp-cron.php

Comment: @TomJNowell I have many attacks to this file and I do not use this... Jetpack. Also I'm talking about restriction from external resources, but not from the server itself. So everything I need should work just fine.

Comment: Have you tried this without the first condition that checks the IP address? Have you confirmed that `wp-cron.php` exists as a physical file in the root? Have you confirmed you are not seeing a cached response? ...clear browser cache, check the network traffic in the browser dev tools as you make the request (also disable cache in dev tools).

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you! It was Cloudflare cache. But now the problem seems to be here:  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1  Because I think it should be Cloudflare IP but not localhost...

Comment: You need to check your access log for the IP(s) when `wp-cron.php` is called "internally". If you are behind Cloudflare then all external traffic comes through on a Cloudflare IP - so you could potentially block the request when it IS a Cloudflare IP (not when it isn't). But Cloudlfare operate over [many _ranges_ of IP addresses](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/ips/). Howeve, it may be preferable to check another HTTP request header instead. Cloudflare sets several headers that start `CF-`. For internal requests, these won't be set. However, doesn't WP set a header when calling `wp-cron.php`?

Comment: Since you have control over crontab, I'd suggest to call your cronjob via php instead of http (or better, via `wp-cli` like `* * * * * cd /wordpress_root; wp cron event run --due-now  > /dev/null 2>&1` ), and deny access to the file entirely via .htaccess ; this way, your server does not generate additional memory overhead on the network layer.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176514/is-there-a-known-vulnerability-for-wp-cron-php